# regex (lookahead) with multiple digits

Tags: java, regex

I have a String which looks like:

`text = "9) text of 9\r\n10) text of 10\r\n11) text of 11\r\n12) ...\r\n123) text of 123"`

I am trying to split it up as follows:

`String[] result = text.split("(?=\\d+\\))");`

The result I am looking for is:

```
- result[0] = "9) text of 9"
- result[1] = "10) text of 10"
- result[2] = "11) text of 11"
- ...
```

But it is not working. Which regex should I use in conjunction with text.split() ?

Comment: what will be desired output  for `9) text of 9 10) text  9 of 10` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you were very close - did you try adding the delimiter prior to the lookahead?

```
String[] result = text.split("\\r\\n(?=\d+\))");
```

I tried it in the JS console (the JS regex is pretty similar to the Java regex processor)

```
let x= "9) text of 9 10) text of 10 11) text of 11 ... 123) text of 123"
let result = x.split(/\\r\\n(?=\d+\))/);
```

result then gives the array you wanted

**Update**: Updated code answer based on updated question

Comment: It works in Java with just the space in front without modifying anything else, just tried it: `s.split(" (?=\\d+\\))")`

Comment: Strange. When I use it with the space in front, the whole String ends up being in result[0].

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that there is also "\r\n\" before each XX) - edited my quesion above. I think that is why it didn't work for me

Comment: Try replacing the space before the parenthesis in the regex I provided with the \\r\\n - that’s what your splitting on - you can also try /s+ there as well

Comment: Replacing the space in the regex with \\r\\n worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The regex `"(\\d+)\\) text of (\\d+)"` will do the trick, like so:

```
String s = "9) text of 9 10) text of 10 11) text of 11 ... 123) text of 123";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\) text of (\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
boolean matchesFound = m.find();
System.out.println("found matches: "+matchesFound);
m.results().map(MatchResult::group).forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output will be:

```
found matches: true
10) text of 10
11) text of 11
123) text of 123
```

If you want to put the results in a list/array instead, just do the following:

```
String s = "9) text of 9 10) text of 10 11) text of 11 ... 123) text of 123";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\) text of (\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
boolean matchesFound = m.find();
System.out.println("found matches: "+matchesFound);
List<String> results = m.results().map(MatchResult::group).map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(results);
String[] resultsAsArray = new String[results.size()];
results.toArray(resultsAsArray);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultsAsArray));
```

The output here will be:

```
found matches: true
[10) text of 10, 11) text of 11, 123) text of 123]
[10) text of 10, 11) text of 11, 123) text of 123]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try lazy quantifier instead of greedy quantifier. Try the below Regex.

```
(\d*\).*?\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

This small line of code will solve your problem.

```
    List<String> matchlist = new ArrayList();
    String text = "9) text of 9 10) text of 10 11) text of 11";
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\)[a-zA-Z\\s]*\\d+");

    Matcher result = regex.matcher(text);
    while (result.find()) {
        matchlist.add(result.group());
    }
    System.out.println(matchlist);
```

The matcher(ArrayList) will contain the required output as shown below:

[9) text of 9, 10) text of 10, 11) text of 11]